# How to install sns

Tags: python, pip, seaborn

I want to use seaborn in idle but to do so I need to install sns. I have tried installing sns as well as pip3 but failed. I am not sure whether pip3 is there or not but I think it is not. I did a lot of research to find how to reinstall pip3 or how to install sns but failed to find it. So can anybody please send the command to check pip3 is installed or how to install sns? Please also tell whether that bit of code has to be written in cmd or command prompt. I was trying to install it by typing first py in cmd and then pip3 install sns but it showed invalid syntax for the word install.

Comment: `py -m pip install seaborn` from CMD

Comment: I do not know why before this command was not working but now it is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `pip3` try only `pip`. `pip install seaborn`.
https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jiten>py
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install seaborn
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install seaborn
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: this is what I am getting this error. I hope I have to write this code in cmd or command prompt.

Comment: @Jitendra You cannot use the Python shell to run pip commands